# URL encoding JSON strings when calling Facebook MarketingAPI

Tags: php, json, facebook, url-encoding

When calling an API endpoint in PHP, what is the difference between passing as a parameter in the URL using

```
$str = '{\'since\':\'2015-01-01\',\'until\':\'2015-01-22\'}';
'blahblah?access_token=xxx&time_range=' . $str;
```

versus

```
 $str = '{\'since\':\'2015-01-01\',\'until\':\'2015-01-22\'}';
'blahblah?access_token=xxx&time_range=' . urlencode($str);
```

Apart from the latter making more likely the URL becoming 'too long'? Knowing that no one is going to see the URL, I just want to retrieve data from the API and output to CSV

Many thanks

Comment: Just a small point. I believe the JSON spec says to use double quotes and not single quotes.

Comment: urlencode as the documentation explains here http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php removes certain characters that a URL cannot be.  For example, if you have a space in between your string such as "hello world", url encoding would replace said "white space" with it's equivalent URL encoding format of %20 (i think that's the code for white space).  The result of the url encoded string "hello world" --> "hello%20world"

Comment: Edit: I'm starting to think the above way of doing things is wrong. The documentation says -d "time_range={'since':'2015-01-01','until':'2015-01-20'}"  so this means passing data in a request body e.g post request via something like

Answer (score 0):

via something like this:

```
$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://api.local/rest/users');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

instead of passing this information in the url via a GET request?

Edit: Actually, can someone just tell me where I can read up on curl command line flags like -G, or how to implement the below in PHP? Thanks

```
curl -G \
-d "fields=['impressions','campaign_group_name','cost_per_action_type']" \
-d "action_breakdowns=['action_type','action_carousel_card_name']" \
-d "level=adgroup" \
-d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/insights"
```